# How to apply reducer over multiple axis?

Tags: python, reducers

I can probably implement it myself, but I would really prefer not to reinvent any wheels.

Given an ndarray, I would like to apply a custom function over each element of some random axis.

The most basic example is applying a function over rows or columns of a a 2darray.

A more advanced example is applying a function over each 3 by 4 *cell* of a 10x20x3x4 ndarray. That would mean that I am applying the function over the axes 2 and 3 (0 based counting).

An even more advanced example would be to apply a function over each 5 by 3 by 4 *cell* of a Ax5xBxCx3xEx4xF ndarray. This would mean that I am applying the function over the axes 1, 4 and 6.

I am sure this functionality must be hidden somewhere in numpy, or maybe even basic python, but I am just not enough versed in Python to know where to start from.

It feels like numpy.ufunc.reduce maybe does what I want, with the exception that it only works for ufuncs and not for custom functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `numpy.ufunc.reduce` with a custom function by using [`numpy.frompyfunc`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.frompyfunc.html#numpy.frompyfunc). Just do something like this:

```
#Example function
def does_it_halt(f, will_the_universe_ever_end):
  if will_the_universe_ever_end:
    return True
  else:
    does_it_halt(f)

# Creates a ufunc given the function object, the number of inputs, and the number of outputs
my_ufunc = numpy.frompyfunc(func=does_it_halt, nin=2, nout=1)
```

Then you can use it something like this:

```
arr = np.arange(24).reshape((2, 3, 4))

>>> array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])

#Group multiple axes
new_arr = np.concatenate([arr[0], arr[1]])

>>> array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23]])

single_dim = new_arr.reshape(24)
>>> array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23])

# And finally reduce it
np.add.reduce(single_dim)
>>> 276
```